# How do I install Windows PowerShell on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Server core installation?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

I found pointers to

```
ocsetup MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell
```

or

```
start ocsetup MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell
```

but they have no effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976736

Title: How to install Windows PowerShell on a computer that is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Core.

*From the article:*

> **Method 1**
>
> 1. Run SCONFIG.
> 2. Select option 4 (Configure Remote Management).
> 3. Select option 2 (Enable Windows PowerShell).
> 4. Click OK.
>
> **Method 2**
>
> Install the following features:
>
> - NetFx2-ServerCore
> - NetFx3-ServerCore
> - NetFx2-ServerCore-WOW64
> - NetFx3-ServerCore-WOW64
> - MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell
> - MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell-WOW64
>
> The following are examples of the commands that install these features:
>
> - DISM.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx2-ServerCore
> - DISM.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3-ServerCore
> - DISM.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx2-ServerCore-WOW64
> - DISM.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3-ServerCore-WOW64
> - DISM.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell
> - DISM.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell-WOW64
>
> **Note** Because Windows PowerShell is built on Microsoft .NET Framework,
>   Microsoft .Net Framework must be installed correctly first for a successful
>   Windows PowerShell installation.

Comment: Be aware...  Method1 does not load any of the *-WOW64 features.  Also, Method2, NetFx3 is not required.